# Jquery fade in/out on hover problem - Stop the blinking!

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein, fadeout

I'm using this script to fade in icons over another when hovered over.

I also want to hide the previous image once the top image is finished fading in.

The problem I am running into is that when you hover over it seems to blink before it fades.  I need the blinking to stop!

Below is my HTML and jQuery code. I tried to make this code somewhat universal.

```
.link-container {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
.title-hover {
    background-position: 0 -106px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 33px;
    margin: -32px 0 0 56px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;

}
.title {
    background-position: 0 -63px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 33px;
    margin: -32px 0 0 56px;
}

<div class="link-container">
     <div class="main-tile hover-init title"></div>
     <div class="main-tile title-hover"></div>
</div>

$(function () {
     $(".link-container").hover(function () {
        $(".hover-init", this).next().stop(true, true).fadeIn(400);
        $(".hover-init", this).hide();
    }, function () {
        $(".hover-init", this).next().stop(true, true).fadeOut(400);
        $(".hover-init", this).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: You didnt post the HTML, just the CSS.

Comment: the jquery was old here is the newest version as well as the html.  Id like to fadein the .next then hide the hover-init.  Then to the opposite for the fadeout.

The method you suggested works, but it doesn't hide the hover-init it just fades the .next on top of the other, which doesn't look very good =/

Comment: you are replying to my answer right ?

Comment: yes cystack im responding to your recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that hover switches from one div to another as the title pops up.
So, you need to sniff what kind of div you are in and vary the response.

Code that does as you ask looks like this:

```
$(".link-container div.main-tile").hover (fancyRollover);

function fancyRollover (zEvent) {
    var jThis           = $(this);
    var bInInitDiv      = jThis.hasClass ('hover-init');
    if (bInInitDiv) {
        var initDiv     = jThis;
        var hoverDiv    = jThis.next ();
    }
    else {
        var initDiv     = jThis.prev ();
        var hoverDiv    = jThis;
    }

    if (zEvent.type == 'mouseenter') {
        if (bInInitDiv) {
            hoverDiv.stop (true, true).fadeIn (400, function () {
                initDiv.hide ();
            } );
        }
        else {
            //--- Do nothing.
        }
    }
    else { //-- zEvent.type == 'mouseleave'
        if (bInInitDiv) {
            //--- Do nothing.
        }
        else {
            hoverDiv.stop (true, true).fadeOut (400);
            initDiv.show ();   
        }
    }
}
```

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7dvDr/4/)

Comment: Brock im not too advanced with Jquery so please forgive my confusion.  I took your piece of code and tried to apply it to my html but it doesn't seem to do anything...any suggestion on why this may be?

Comment: How does your code differ from the code in the question and the code in the fiddle?  (The fiddle is identical to the question, except for minor CSS adjustments to show the action.)  This answer jQuery should drop right in to a page as described in the question.  Can you link to the actual page?

Comment: i managed to fix it so the your code works but now i run into a new problem, take a look at the link at the end of this comment and hover over the "resume" link. Both the icon and text should fade in and out together, using your code they seem to be treated seperatly.  Even the hover over the name does not seem to be smooth [LINK HERE](http://www.norkenguitars.com/new)

Comment: They are treated separately because they are in different `div`s.  That structure is different than what the question posted!  If you want the divs linked, **open a new question**.  *This* question has been addressed as posted.  Also, right now, it looks like things are just turning blue on hover.  If that's all, then separate images and swapping divs are not needed.  A transparent image and some CSS would work.   Also, use jQuery 1.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

You want to start the fadeOut AFTER the fadeIn finishes, right ? Then make it a callback of the fadeIn function :

```
$(".hover-init", this).next().stop(true, true).fadeIn(400, function() {
  $(".hover-init", this).fadeOut();
});
```

EDIT :

now that I see the effect you want to achieve I don't even know why you want to fadeOut the first div.

http://jsfiddle.net/ARyjq/3/  do that

Comment: so the fadeOut fails ? try symply `$(this).fadeOut()` instead of `$(".hover-init", this).fadeOut()`

Comment: with your method it doesn't give an error just fades one image on top of the other.  With the method i have in my post it seems to hide the image then fade in which causes a blink.  Im looking for a way to fadein one image then hide the other that way there is no blink. so no error with either method

Comment: yes but that will look strange too, no ? one appears, THEN other disappears... Ill look into your code (did the `$(this)` not fix it ?)

Comment: `$(this)` did not fix it.  It just created a continuous blinking effect. Fading one image then hide the other shouldn't look strange because once the image on top is faded in the bottom one should disappear without anyone noticing

here is a link to the project i am working on now, it may make it easier to see my problem.  This sample is currently using the code in the original post.  You can notice when you hover over any button or the name it is not a smooth fade in and out.  [Sample](http://www.norkenguitars.com/new)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ARyjq/  here is your solution, simplified. Notice that positioning has to be absolute for the 2 divs tzo be on top of another.

Comment: Also there is a typo on your site : "use the contact FORM below" not from ;)

Comment: is there a way to do this without referring directly to title-hover? I'd like to use this script with more than one link thats why ive been using the .next command

Comment: of course, just change it to `$(this).next()` like in here http://jsfiddle.net/ARyjq/1/

Comment: I edited my answer with the exact effect you want. no need to fadeOut the first div. http://jsfiddle.net/ARyjq/3/

Comment: with your last edit, the original image does not disappear.  This isnt a problem much with text but with images i need this to happen because they look bad when they are on top of one another